# How to prevent code that degrades program performance from being merged into the master branch

Tags: git, performance, cicd

I'm currently working on a database performance evaluation. In order to judge whether the newly submitted code has factors that cause the program performance to deteriorate, I created a code performance evaluation process on the build platform of the code repository. The specific method is to run test cases of specific scenarios on the program and record the running time and throughput. Run time and throughput are averaged over multiple iterations. The average of 0.95 times is then used as a performance indicator. The newly submitted code will automatically execute these test cases, and if these indicators are not met, it cannot be merged into the main branch to achieve the purpose of intercepting degrading performance code. I wonder if what I'm doing like this can really measure the performance of the program, and if it's reasonable to measure the way a program runs. At the same time, I found that in the case of fluctuations in the machine, it needs to be repeated many times to succeed. I'm wondering how you guys prevent codes that degrades program performance from being merged into the main branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you use one of the common git hosting providers (like [github](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches) or [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html)), you can achieve something like this through protected branches and required status checks.

Comment: Yes, I'm using gitlab. I have created bash script in gitlab automatic build. In the script I set the baseline of the program's execution to be the average of the program's running time over a period of time. I would like to know how to determine the performance of the program more scientifically.

Comment: How about creating an integration test that benchmarks the code, and fails if does not meet your threshold?